# Localhost exception in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, security

I have a MongoDB database installed and configured, but I have a very big problem regarding security.

I have enabled authentication and created a bunch of users, each with its own permissions, everything ok there, now my problem is that if a bad guy gets access to my server, he can simply restart the service without specifying the authentication parameter, and access all my databases just by logging in with the localhost.

In the documentation it says:

> The localhost exception applies only when there are no users created
>   in the MongoDB instance.

Well, I have already created users, and I am still able to access my database using the localhost exception. Am I doing anything wrong? Or is the documentation wrong? If so, this seems to be a major security problem.

The Mongo version I am using is 3.4.

These are the steps I followed to enable authentication:

1. Joined Mongo without the `--auth` parameter
2. Created an Admin User

   ```
    use admin

    var user = {
      "user" : "Admin",
      "pwd" : "1234",
      roles : [
        {
          "role" : "root",
          "db" : "admin"
        }
      ]}

    db.createUser(user);
   ```
3. Restarted Mongo with the `--auth` parameter
4. Created a database and some collections

   ```
   use TestDB
   db.createCollection( "TestCollection1" );
   db.createCollection( "TestCollection2" );
   ```
5. Created a custom role:

   ```
   use TestDB

   db.runCommand({ createRole:"TestUserRole",
     privileges : [
        { "resource": {"db" : "TestDB", "collection" : "TestCollection1"}, "actions": ["insert", "update"] },
        { "resource": {"db" : "TestDB", "collection" : ""}, "actions": ["insert"] }
      ],
      "roles" : [ { role: "read", db: "TestDB" } ]
    })
   ```
6. Created a regular user

   ```
   use TestDB

   var user = {
     "user" : "TestUser",
     "pwd" : "1234",
      roles : [
         {
             "role" : "TestUserRole",
             "db" : "TestDB"
         }
   ]}

   db.createUser(user);
   ```

After this, I can access Mongo with both users, with the Admin account I can find, insert, update and delete in both collections of the database TestDB. With the user TestUser, I can only see the database TestDB (can't see the System collections) and can only find, insert and update TestCollection1, and can only find and insert in TestCollection2.

This is the behaviour I want, all working fine. Now, if I restart Mongo without the `--auth` parameter, I shouldn't be able to connect to Mongo using the localhost exception because users are already created. Yet I am able to connect.

Comment: The tutorial for [Enable Auth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) in the MongoDB manual has the steps for correctly enabling authentication. Extra details that would be helpful are the steps or output that suggest unauthenticated data access is still possible after you enabled auth.

Comment: Posted the edit. Yes, that was the tutorial that I followed, I don't know if it is important, but I am using Mongo as a windows service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Authentication only controls access to clients connecting to a MongoDB deployment. Securing [remote access to your server](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/#limit-network-exposure) or [encrypting your data files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/#encrypt-and-protect-data) are separate security measures.

If an attacker is able to gain access to a shell on your server and run privileged commands (like restarting the `mongod` service), access control is irrelevant. Similarly, even if your data files were encrypted an attacker with privileged access will be a major security problem.

As the administrator of a server, it is your responsibility to have appropriate access control, firewalls, auditing, and other security measures in place. Security involves multiple layers of defense, and access control is only a starting point. At a minimum you should also enable [network encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/#encrypt-communication) (TLS/SSL) and appropriately [limit network exposure](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/#limit-network-exposure).

For a list of recommended security measures, see the [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/).

> Now, if I restart Mongo without the --auth parameter, I shouldn't be able to connect to Mongo using the localhost exception.

If you restart MongoDB without the `--auth` parameter (or equivalent configuration file directive), you are explicitly disabling access control and allowing clients to connect without requiring authentication. This may be useful for administrative intervention, such as resetting a forgotten admin password.

Comment: Hmn, if that is the expected behaviour of Mongo DB the documentation is wrong, and in my opinion is a security problem. Are you sure that its the expected behaviour?

Comment: Access control is disabled by default as at MongoDB 3.4, so as per the [Enable Auth tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) you need to have access control enabled and authentication configured. Presence of authentication data does not automatically enable access control, so if a system administrator restarts MongoDB without enabling access control (or uses a backup of the data on another deployment without access control) is is expected that clients will be able to connect without auth.

Comment: The [localhost exception](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#localhost-exception) only enables creating the initial user when access control is *enabled*. Which documentation link(s) would you suggest improving? FYI, you can also provide feedback directly on docs pages (there's a green "Was this page helpful?" prompt in the bottom right corner leading to "fix this page") or add feedback in the [DOCS project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS) in MongoDB's Jira issue tracker.